# Springboot Websockets : Could not read JSON: Cannot deserialize instance of `someclass` out of START_ARRAY token

Tags: json, spring-boot, jackson, spring-websocket

I'm trying to send a JSON object via websockets in SpringBoot, however on my controller I'm getting following error :

```
org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Could not read JSON: Cannot deserialize instance of `com.websocket.demo.bean.MessageBean` out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: (byte[])"[object Object]"; line: 1, column: 1]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `com.websocket.demo.bean.MessageBean` out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: (byte[])"[object Object]"; line: 1, column: 1]
    at org.springframework.messaging.converter.MappingJackson2MessageConverter.convertFromInternal(MappingJackson2MessageConverter.java:235) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.converter.AbstractMessageConverter.fromMessage(AbstractMessageConverter.java:181) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.converter.CompositeMessageConverter.fromMessage(CompositeMessageConverter.java:70) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.support.PayloadArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(PayloadArgumentResolver.java:137) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:116) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:109) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.AbstractMethodMessageHandler.handleMatch(AbstractMethodMessageHandler.java:517) [spring-messaging-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.simp.annotation.support.SimpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler.handleMatch(SimpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler.java:495) [spring-messaging-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.simp.annotation.support.SimpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler.handleMatch(SimpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler.java:88) [spring-messaging-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.AbstractMethodMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractMethodMessageHandler.java:475) [spring-messaging-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.AbstractMethodMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMethodMessageHandler.java:411) [spring-messaging-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.support.ExecutorSubscribableChannel$SendTask.run(ExecutorSubscribableChannel.java:138) [spring-messaging-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_181]
```

This is how my controller looks like :

```
 //This is intended to particular user;
   @MessageMapping("/message")
   public void processMessage( MessageBean message/* @DestinationVariable int id, @DestinationVariable int targetUserId*/ )
   {
      String channel = userService.generateConnectionString( message.getRecieverId() );
      boolean isError = false;
      if ( channel == null )
      {
         isError = true;
      }
      Map< String, Object > response = generateResponse( isError, channel, "Connection Request Sent Successfuly" );
      messagingTemplate.convertAndSend( "/queue/greeting/" + message.getRecieverId(), response);
   }
```

The request object that I'm trying to send :

```
$scope.sendMessage1 = function()
    {   
        $scope.subscribe(1);
        $scope.message = {};
        $scope.message.senderId = 2;
        $scope.message.recieverId = 1;
        $scope.message.text = "Hello from user 2";
        var sendObject = JSON.stringify($scope.message);
        //sendObject = "{"senderId":1,"recieverId":2,"text":"Hello from user 1"}"
        console.log(sendObject);
        client.send("/app/message",{},sendObject);
    };
```

Can someone tell me how to resolve this Exception?

Comment: It's not clear from your question and example what client library you are using to connect and send data to the Spring Websocket.  Are you using STOMP on the server and SockJS on the client side?

Comment: I'm using this librart on the client side, https://github.com/JSteunou/webstomp-client

Comment: Did you find a solution for this ?